# is there basemaps for Qgis 2.99

Tags: qgis, openlayers, basemap

What i have:
I've installed Qgis 2.99.0 (dev)

How do I:
Install base map for this version. The openlayers plugin isn't available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a basemap using any WMS of your choice without the need of OpenLayers, by using the "Add WMS/WMST" button.
The OpenStreetMap wiki has a [list](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WMS#OSM_WMS_Servers) of some WMS you could use.

Comment: Glad to hear that! If the answer solves your problem, can you please click the green tick sign on the left? This marks the question as solved.